# Invoking a private GCF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to invoke a GCF whose network settings I set to "allow internal traffic only" as per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#create-internal-function), via curl from a GCE instance in the same project. I am getting a 403 error.

According to the above docs:

> VM instances inside your project or service perimeter can still reach your function by making requests to its HTTPS endpoint.

How can I ensure requests coming from within the same project are able to access the private GCF as per the documentation and don't receive 403 responses as I'm seeing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible layer of security: network and identity

The ingress internal is the network security layer: it checks if the request come from the networks of your project. In your case, it should be OK

The second level is the identity. You can restrict the access to your Cloud Functions with IAM (default setting). You can make your cloud functions public by allowing allUsers with the role cloudfunctions.invoker.

*Of course here, public mean anyone in your project because the ingress is internal, like inside a DMZ*.

---

Check that second parameter